# Apple root certificate for push notifications on openshift

Tags: python, django, apple-push-notifications, openshift

I am stuck on this step of the APNs (Apple Push Notification) process.  I have app-specific certificates and keys from developer.apple.com that work fine for a local dev server on my OSX system, but on my RHEL based OpenShift cloud servers they don't seem to work.  There is this cryptic step from Apple's documentation.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH101-SW1

> Note: To establish a TLS session with APNs, an Entrust Secure CA root certificate must be installed on the provider’s server. If the server is running OS X, this root certificate is already in the keychain. On other systems, the certificate might not be available. You can download this certificate from the Entrust SSL Certificates website.

I did obtain said certificate, as both a .der and .cer from this site.

https://www.entrust.net/downloads/root_request.cfm#

Now where do I put them?  I am running a Django app (might switch in the future, but a separate topic) on OpenShift.

Comment: Thank you for the correction: RHEL-based.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send apple push notifications from a shared server or PaaS , you will probably have to use a third party such as http://urbanairship.com/.

Comment: I am skeptical that there isn't a way to do this directly in code or configuration.  That having been said, urbanairship seems like overkill.  I see some OpenShift cartridges and Heroku options that might be more appropriate.